# Сокращение записи namespace::Класс::Метод

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

Есть класс. Вот его заголовок:

```
namespace FlightController
{
    public ref class FlightController
    {
        public:
            FlightController();
    };
}
```

По моему запросу студия сама добавила конструктор в *.cpp* следующего вида:

```
#include "FlightController.h"

FlightController::FlightController::FlightController()
{
    throw gcnew System::NotImplementedException();
}
```

Меня смущает вот это:

```
FlightController::FlightController::FlightController()
```

Если я в файл *.cpp* добавляю `using namespace FlightController;`, то компилятор выдает ошибку:

> FlightController неоднозначный символ

Можно ли избавиться от необходимости в файле исходного кода писать `namespace::Класс::Метод`? Есть ли возможность сократить это до `Метод` или `Класс::Метод`?

Comment: а вы когда `добавляю using namespace FlightController;` убирали часть неймспейса?

Comment: @Grundy, какую часть неймспейса? Не понял. Ошибка возникает на описании конструктора, а не на строке using namespace

Comment: я имел ввиду когда добавляете `using namespace FlightController;` оставляете: `FlightController::FlightController::FlightController()` или `FlightController::FlightController()`

Comment: @iRumba Любопытно, а почему вы решили заняться C++/CLI?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, потому что этого требует учеба :) На самом деле про CLR разговора не было, просто это на зло преподу, который принудил меня писать проект на плюсах, а не самому выбирать язык. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте написать так:

```
namespace FlightController
{

    FlightController::FlightController()
    {
        ...
    }

    // остальные методы
}
```

Когда вы пишете `using namespace FlightController`, у вас внешний `FlightController` может быть как `namespace`, так и `class`. В случае, когда вы находитесь внутри `namespace FlightController`, первый вариант отпадает — разве что для случая, когда внутри `namespace FlightController` есть ещё *вложенный* `namespace FlightController`!

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы избежать этой неоднозначности, добавьте еще пару двоеточий для "полного счастья".:) Например

```
::FlightController::FlightController::FlightController()
^^^
```

Тогда поиск имен начнется с глобального пространства имен.

Конечно вы облегчили бы себе жизнь, если бы не использовали одно и то же имя для пространства имен и класса. Это самое простое решение.